# Reactive form giving error Property 'email' does not exist on type 'AppComponent'

Tags: angular, forms, reactive

I am trying to apply reactive form validation. But it is not working. Giving error "Property 'email' does not exist on type 'AppComponent'."
the source code is on  this link https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-y3hup7?file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: What about changing email.errors.required ---> signupForm.email..errors.required ?

Comment: @Rebai still getting same error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should access formcontrols in a group using get method `signupForm.get('email')`.

Have forked your slackblitz with the solution applied
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-lciego?file=src/app/app.component.html

```html
<form [formGroup]="signupForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit();">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="email">Email address:</label>
    <input type="email" formControlName="email" name='email' class="form-control" id="email" required >
    <div *ngIf="signupForm.get('email').invalid && 
                (signupForm.get('email').dirty || signupForm.get('email').touched)" class="alert alert-danger">

      <div *ngIf="signupForm.get('email')?.errors?.required">
        Email is required.
      </div>
      <div *ngIf="signupForm.get('email')?.errors?.email">
        Invalid email
      </div>
     
    </div>

  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="pwd">Password:</label>
    <input type="password" formControlName="password" name='password' class="form-control" id="pwd" required  >
  </div>
  <button [disabled]="!signupForm.valid" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>

<!-- <router-outlet></router-outlet> -->
```